# Is it possible to make DIY foam tire inserts for gravel bikes?

Tags: tubeless, gravel, diy, foam, inserts

I [saw a video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=G30pC_fSgaY) of the British cyclocross racers putting foam from a hardware store into their tires. This foam is used in construction to fill joints before caulking.  All those joints on the concrete interstates in the US are filled with foam backer rod covered by caulk. FYI, CX magazine has a writeup on their experience [here](https://www.cxmagazine.com/diy-tubeless-tire-inserts-whats-the-difference-part-2). Here is a [forum discussion](https://www.trainerroad.com/forum/t/tire-inserts-for-xc-racing/17748?page=3) on TrainerRoad about DIY CX tire inserts.

Do DIY tubeless inserts like this work on gravel bikes? If so, how well do they work? I ask because cyclocross tires are wider than traditional gravel tires.

Additional questions might include:

1. What should I look for in a foam tube? I fear that the backer rod used in the CX Magazine article above will be too narrow for a gravel tire. Foam inserts for MTB tires will be too large. FYI, there's some discussion on [MTBR here](https://www.mtbr.com/threads/diy-tire-insert-experiment.1045458/page-4).
2. How well do they perform long term?
3. How easily do they install, and are there any tricks to getting them installed?

There's not a lot of info online but from the video it looked like it did work.  The DIY section of this article is probably the best description I found:

Comment: Reviews are off topic on this site, however you are welcomed (and encouraged) to answer your own question. If you could formulate this into a question that other people may find knowing the answer to useful (and avoid product recommendations and such) you are welcome to post it up here.

Comment: Concur with @mattnz   Juggle this around so it is a question, ("do ghetto foam inserts help in tubeless tyres?") and the bulk of this would form an answer-post.

Comment: Well, you kind of already given enough information for people to be interested in it.
If it does really work, then it would be a bit like lube your bicycle chain with wax, it really works and it has it's own energy to take off all on it's own, but it can take time because, as you said with foam tyres, it takes time to do it properly, and that's the key for success.  
There are already airless tyre products that have a patent, and are in development at a commercial rate. Look at Gecko Rubber 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXAkzNTL2tc

Comment: I didn't think the write-up would fit the format of the site well but since there is interest and I'm being told to go ahead, I'll edit it and post as an answered question soon.

Comment: See the edited question for an example of how you might phrase this as a question. If this doesn't work for you, you can undo the edit.

Comment: @PaulH A simple mistake in one sentence, the following point 1 clears that issue.

Comment: how am I supposed to mark this question answered when there are no answers and when I post an answer for the sole purpose of marking the question answered someone deletes it before I can do so?  I guess this question will just stay unanswered, and I'm not gonna repeat what I said in my answer.

Comment: For a Q&A site it's really hard to mark questions answered here. I tried to do so yesterday but the site said I had to wait 4 hours to mark my own question answered. When I woke up this morning and clicked the check mark the site said the answer was deleted. After I posted a comment it refreshed and I see the question, answer and comments are totally different. The original question was answered; I will edit and post the test results as a new question. It might take me a few weeks. Also, any time I try to thank anyone here it gets deleted so I guess that's not allowed. Seems rude to me.

Comment: You can thank people by upvoting their comment or answer. Again, this isn't a typical forum. Also, with the question as it is, it's reasonable for you to post an answer right now, which you can then accept later.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:  Yes it is possible to make a foam insert for your gravel bike's tyres.

Downside: It’ll increase the wheel weight. Mass does affect the angular velocity. It will slow you down especially when climbing where you have to accelerate that weight.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/57849)

Comment: Could you expand on "how" and perhaps some of the sub-questions in the original post ?

Comment: How is the weight of the DIY-insert a downside compared to the ones that the OP would purchase? Do you expect ta DIY insert to weigh significantly more than store-bought insert?

Comment: Ok, logically speaking you have narrowly answered. If the question was “ can I jump off a bridge?” Would you tell the OP that yes it is possible. Not mentioning the physics which says it isn’t advised? HVAC

Comment: The OP did ask if this method would work on gravel bikes. 
If the question is answered narrowly, it will miss the point entirely. Certainly I “can jump off a bridge.” Or ask you to suggest a series of bridge heights. The answer is absurd without mentioning the physics involved. If that’s off subject, well that’s just silly. Who does that ?

Comment: The three inserts I made and tested weighed 22g, 37g and 47g, including the zip ties (700c, 29-37mm foam diameter). That's far less than a commercial insert because they use denser foam that we can't get. The sealant needed to cover the extra surface area roughly tripled the weight of my inserts. FYI I've been working on the write-up but it's still a rambling mess and I can't promise I'll ever finish. :-/ I'm happy to answer specific questions if you can find a way to make the site notify me when you've posted one.